# Have CRTs ever used a different raking pattern?

Tags: history, crt

CRTs traditionally scan top-left to bottom-right, in a row-major raking pattern, and appear to have done so since the 1930s. This is a little unusual though, as standard mathematical orientations have Y increasing *upward*, not *downward*, and the behavior of these screens has had a lasting, and likely predictable, impact on software modeling and rasters.

My question is of a electronics-history nature. Have we ever tried any CRT raster displays that weren't aligned this way, as a default? Was there ever a CRT device that scanned in a traditional, bottom-left-to-top-right, or even column-major, order? Why did we settle on top-left-to-bottom-right?

Thanks to anyone who can shed a little light on this for me.

Comment: Look up vector displays. The Vectrex comes to mind in particular.

Comment: an oscilloscope sweeps left to right Y+ at top of display ... it is unclear what you mean by `traditional`

Comment: Have a look at CRT RADAR displays.

Comment: @jsotola — right you are. I've clarified my question, oscilloscopes don't really have that much to do with the core of my question anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a design question.  It could almost fit on retrocomputing SE except that it isn't actually about computing specifically.

Comment: I suppose that's fair, but do you have any suggestions as to where else on the web I should look for this information? Even if it isn't a Stack Exchange? I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Top to bottom scanning, then left to right, was used in the 1920s, seen in a retrospective (from 1937!) here. http://www.bairdtelevision.com/firstdemo.html
That wasn't a CRT of course.

Comment: It is relevant to the question, though—thank you! It's kind of comical reading over that today.

Comment: Didn't Clive Sinclair come up with a TV viewed from the electron-beam side instead of the outer glass side? He'd have had to reverse the raster scanning.